# .Net Maui - A debugger is attached to [myapp].exe but not configured

Tags: .net, exception, debugging, maui

I am developing a .net maui app/frontend app and randomly today began receiving the error "An unhandled win32 exception occurred in myapp.exe." with the addition Warning Alert "A debugger is attached to myapp.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception. To debug this exception, detach the current debugger."
The app had been working perfectly fine all day and the only changes made at the time was creating a new viewmodel. I tried reverting my changes to the previous state when it was working but this did not fix it.

**UPDATE:**
I have debugged further and added a new image of the debug exception.

[Exception Image HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y30ct.png)

**Additional Notes:**

- VS2022 & the app is in .net6/core6.
- Debugger Type Settings has Managed, Native, & Script all selected (shown below).
- I have tried disabling the JIT Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Select all checks for exceptions settings.CLR Exception.
Works for me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isX9Y.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This didn't work for me. I'm still getting the same message.